# Pairs of subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Suppose we have two subfactors $P\subset M$ and $Q\subset M$ with finite Jones indices (here $P,Q$ and $M$ all are $II_1$ factors). Under what condition the von Neumann algebra $L$ generated by $M,e_P$ and $e_Q$ namely $\{M,e_P,e_Q\}^{\prime\prime}\subset \mathcal{B}(L^2(M))$ is a $II_1$ factor? When is $[L:M]$ finite? Note that if $P=Q$ this is known by the paper:

Index for Subfactors, VFR Jones, Inventiones mathematicae, 1983.

Comment: If dealing with $L'=J(P\cap Q)J$, then Jones and Xu's paper: Intersections of finite index families of finite index subfactors, is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Jiang. You are right. This will answer my second question (finiteness of $[L:M]$). But it seems that they have not discussed anything about the factoriality of $P\cap Q$.

Comment: Some Information may be found in the following recent preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.07197